# mark packets by multiple rule

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have a problem with iptables rules.  This is my scenario:

eth2: Internet connection

br1:  local network

I want to mark only packets entering from the Internet interface(eth2) destinated to local net(br1).  How to mark packets with src eth2, dst and IP address?

Answer (score 1):

you can match both input and intended output interfaces in the FORWARD chain with "-i eth2 -o br1"